# Падеж в словосочетании "поили коня"

Tags: падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Здравствуйте, есть сомнения. Как правильно определить винительный или родительный падеж в словосочетании "поили коня"?

Answer (score 3):

Можно заменить слово *"конь"* на любое другое (желательно неодушевленное, ввиду совпадения падежей у одушевленных) и посмотреть, в каком падеже оно будет стоять. Например, *"поили матрёшку"* — винительный падеж. Следовательно, в словосочетании *"поили коня"* слово *"конь"* стоит в винительном падеже.

Comment: Лучше все-таки заменять на слово того же грамматического склонения.
Поить табун, например.  

Во всяком случае ваше замечание по поводу неодошевлённости приобретает хоть какой-то смысл. У "матрешек"-то все падежи разные, независимо от одушевлённости.

Comment: Вот для таких и приходится ставить точки над ё.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала определяет одуш\неодуш. сущ-ого. **КОНЬ** - одуш. сущ.(В.п. мн. ч. равен Р. п.мн. ч.: я вижу коней (В. п.) = нет коней (Р. п.). А так как слово "поить" требует В. п. (кого? что?), то поить (кого?) *коня*, но поить (что?) землю водой.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Валентином, только не заменяем, а берём оба падежных вопроса для одуш. и неод.:
нет кого? чего?-коня,стола.
Вижу кого?что? - коня, стол. 
Не совпадает в  винительном. Но нам и слова  не нужны, только вопросы:кого?чего?-родит., кого?что? - винительный. Так учат в начальных классах.

Соан сразу сказала: "поили" требует вин. пад.(кого? что?) - глагол сильного управления - что доказывать?Это я и имела в виду.Но если человек не понимает,в 4 классе объясняют так:1.Поставь вопрос.   Кого?(Что?)
2.Определи склонение:  В 1 всё понятно – птицу (у Валентина матрёшку)
3.2 –е замени 1-м,  и всё будет понятно: поили кого? –коня, птицу. Птицу не перепутаешь, точно вин., значит, и коня - вин.
(УМК "Школа России" авт. Т.Г. Рамзаева)
http://nsportal.ru/nachalnaya-shkola/russkii-yazyk/russkii-yazyk-4-klass-uch-tg-ramzaevoi
Валентин только не добавил, что заменяем на 1 скл.Он прав.Соан сказала то же самое(землю), но дольше.

Comment: Людмила, Вы немножко не правы. Определяется одуш/неод. сущ-ого во МНОЖЕСТВЕННОМ числе, а не в единственном. Вот так учат в школе. 
Поэтому, нет (кого? что?) - коней,цветы;
         вижу(кого? что?)- коней,цветы.

Comment: Так ведь спросили не о том, как определить од./неод., а как определить падеж слова "коня" именно в ед. ч., а его определяют по вопросам, но в сущ. одуш. они совпадают, поэтому вопрос к неод. уточняет категорию:кого?чего?//кого? что? Разве не по вопросам определяют падеж в школе? В чём же я не права?

Comment: Людмила, я тоже не совсем понимаю, что именно вы хотите сказать. 
Вопрос был о падеже слова в единственном числе. Говоря более "высоким" языком, каким падежом управляет глагол "поить". Как вариант решения (один из) предлагается воспользоваться заменой на множественное число, для которого формы не совпадают. Мне не совсем нравится этот подход, но он по крайней мере понятен. А вы-то что предлагаете взамен? Вспомнить, что к родительному падежу вопрос "чего?", а к винительному - "что?"   Ну допустим, а как этим воспользоваться?!

Comment: Поили коня и папу (в.п.), первым упал конь...)))

Comment: Вот-вот, шутка-каламбур помогает понять падеж. Не вижу сложностей в вопросе.